# I have a problem with fragments in android incompatible fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

The problem is the incompatible types in the fragments. Please, check down I don't know what to do know.

Here is the code:

```
 case R.id.mwelcome:
                  currentFragment = new WelcomeFragment(); // the problem is here incompatible types
              break;
                  currentFragment = new MapFragment();     // the problem is here incompatible types
          case R.id.map:
              break;
```

The problem is incopatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two Fragment classes available in Android:

- android.app.Fragment
- android.support.v4.app.Fragment

Since you haven't actually provided much code, I can only guess, but I'm fairly certain your `currentFragment` variable is one of these Fragment types, while your WelcomeFragment and MapFragment objects are of the other type.

Make sure you're using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` in everything, as `android.app.Fragment` has been deprecated. Check your imports and fix them if needed.

Comment: wow you are so fantastic jajaj sorry my english is bad xD jajaja. but thanks you so much friend :).  what you told me works xD :).